# Subindo Aplicação Laravel4 para hospedagem compartilhada

Tags: laravel-4, deploy

[image: Gerenciador]

Meu acesso a essa hospedagem só poder ser da pasta `public_html` pra frente, não consigo acessas um nível atrás.

Coloquei todos os arquivos do projeto dentro de `public_html` e inseri um `htaccess` com

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

e não deu certo, me retorna uma página em branco.

O que será que tem de errado?

Comment: O Laravel tem permissão de escrita na pasta `app/storage`? Certifique-se também de que todas as extensões que o Laravel necessita estão instaladas e ativadas como: JSON, Mcrypt e outras.

Comment: a pasta `app/storage` está com as permissões e as extensões estão todas instaladas... para teste de deploy eu peguei um repositório do github que está ativo e funcionando...

Answer (score 2):

A única forma que encontrei no compartilhado que uso é:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Essa questão do .htaccess varia da versão do apache, e a forma como ele compilado, esse mesmo código não funciona no host de um amigo.

Pode ser que funcione pra você. Mas não posso dar certeza.

Comment: Não sei porque, mas não está dando certo...  pra testar eu peguei o repositório do tutorial todovel no github e fiz do jeito que ele ensinou mas não teve jeito